# Changing the title image of a TitledPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Using a listener I intend to change the background image of a TitledPane even though I have not achieved it. When you start the code, the stylesheet shows 'DownArrow' but when you expand/collapse the TitledPane, the image disappears and nothing is displayed. The images I use are in the same folder as the code and the style sheet. The code I am using is the following:

```
        titledPane.expandedProperty().addListener((obs, wasExpanded, nowExpanded) -> {
            if (nowExpanded) {        
                titledPane.lookup(".title").setStyle(
                     "-fx-background-image : url('DownArrow.png'); " 
                );
            } else {
                titledPane.lookup(".title").setStyle(
                    "-fx-background-image : url('LeftArrow.png'); " 
                );                
            }
        });
```

CSS file:

```
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-image : url('DownArrow.png'); 
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-position: right;
}
```

Comment: Try to print a sentence in the if and else statements to check if it's really getting in

Comment: try this in css instead ? .title {
    -fx-background-image : url('DownArrow.png'); 
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-position: right;
}